# how to call class of other modules on click android

Tags: android, import, module

I have developed 2 modules(A and B) and imported both of them in a third single module(C). Now what I want is that on click of a button (of module C) call class of module A and same for B.Please if it is possible,then someone let me know how it will work.

Comment: hello, add some code to show what you are up to now with code. this is not like forum..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `call class` mean? If you want to use class of other modules, just add the dependency in `gradle` file of module C:

```
compile project(path: ':A')
compile project(path: ':B')
```

Comment: i have done this, But i am asking about intent. how to call the activity(class) through intent

Comment: you mean startActivity(intent)? just declare your intent(context, yourDesiredActivity.class).